# Is there a pre-existing class to define a sequence of operations on numbers in Java?

Tags: java

I'm developing a graphical user interface in Java and relying on the standard MVC design pattern in which I have a View which should provide an up-to-date representation of the state of the Model.

I have an `ObserverTextField` class within the View which subclasses `JTextField` and registers itself as an observer of part of the Model. When this part of the Model changes, it calls this observer's `notify` method, passing the integer value. The class then sets its displayed text to the user.

However, I would like to be able to control the representation of the number at run-time. I could pass a `NumberFormat` to the class, but that doesn't seem able to represent the value as, say, 1/1000th of its actual value.

E.g. if the model stores the value of a current in milliamps, and I want it shown to the user in terms of amps, is there some kind of object I could construct and pass to the `ObserverTextField` to let it do that?

Below is an example of the code using an instance of `NumberFormat`, which I would like to replace with something more powerful:

```
public class ObserverTextField extends JTextField implements Observer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private NumberFormat formatter;

    @Override
    public void notify(Object value) {
        if(formatter == null) {
            setText(String.valueOf(value));
        } else {
            setText(formatter.format((int)value));
        }
    }

    public NumberFormat getFormat() {
        return formatter;
    }

    public void setFormat(NumberFormat formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }
}
```

If there isn't such a thing, I could create my own, but I'd prefer to make sure something like that doesn't already exist in Java's standard library first.

Comment: I'm not sure the two first paragraphs are relevant for your question.

Comment: @Dici I'm including it just to make it clear what I mean when I talk about the Model and View further down. I talk about those things just to make my motivation clear.

Comment: So is not as easy a a simple conversion from milliamps to amps before presenting it as a String?

Comment: @gtgaxiola Where would the conversion be done, though? I shouldn't be hard-coding this anywhere.

(Edit) The Model class shouldn't care about how the value is presented - it always passes its raw state to its observers. The observer needs to be able to dynamically change the way it represents values at run-time (to promote code re-use).

Comment: i think you are mixing (misunderstanding) conversion and format.. conversion will change the value, but format will change how the value looks like,,, and no shame in hardcoding the conversion, `int valInAmps = (int)value/1000;` then set this in textField, either Formatted or Not

Comment: @yazan agree with you... I think the OP is over analyzing this

Comment: @Yazan `int valInAmps = (int)value/1000;` And where would you implement that code? If you hardcode the logic in like that you damage code re-use. The answers provided below make it easier to change the way that the value is represented at run-time.

Comment: it depends on your UI and logic you try to implement, anyway, one place to do this is before passing it to the `notify()`, convert, format then pass to `notify()` so the View will only View the data, nothing more, this is my personal opinion.

Comment: @Yazan But the thing that calls `notify()` is the Model class, and that doesn't know or care what is actually receiving the information (beyond the fact that they are an `Observer`) or care about how they represent it. In addition, the Model iterates through all of its observers and passes them all the same data, so it wouldn't work if different observers expected the data formatted in different ways. In my opinion it seems best to let the Model not know or care about how the data is represented, and put the responsibility on the observer as people have suggested in the answers below.

Comment: agree, my comment was about mixing format & conversion which looks not the case, so nothing more to say :), you can add a factor as @gtgaxiola suggested in your TextField class, just as the formatter, and apply both at the notify()

Comment: @Yazan Yeah gtgaxiola's solution could certainly work. I was really just curious to see if Java already had a standard way of doing this (i.e. something like `NumberFormat` which converts as well as formats). Since it doesn't seem to, I went ahead and built a `MathSequence` utility class which I provided in my answer below. It suits my needs and keeps the code re-usable so I'm happy enough for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Observer can have a utility function that will Format your value as so:

```
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

public static String getFormattedValue(double value, double factor) {
    return df.format(value * factor);
}
```

Here is an example in `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double value = 3560;
    System.out.println(value + " milliamps");
    //Milliamps to centiamps is a factor of .1
    System.out.println(getFormattedValue(value, .1) + " centiamps");
    //Milliamps to deciamps is a facotr of .01
    System.out.println(getFormattedValue(value, .01) + " deciamps");
    //Milliamps to amps is a factor of .001
    System.out.println(getFormattedValue(value, .001) + " amps");

}
```

The output:

```
3560.0 milliamps
356.000 centiamps
35.600 deciamps
3.560 amps
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this answer but Joop's is also pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 promises a nice solution:

```
textField.setFormat((n) -> (n.intValue() / 1000) + " mA");

private Function<Number, String> formatter = (n) -> n + " A";

@Override
public void notify(Object value) {
    setText(formatter.apply((Number)value));
}

public void setFormat(Function<Number, String> formatter) {
    this.formatter = formatter;
}
```

Comment: Excellent usage of the new features!

Comment: Thanks! I can only accept one answer I'm afraid but I've upvoted yours as it seems like a good solution as well. The lambda expressions Java 8 introduces look really awesome, but I'm trying to steer clear of them for now just to ensure backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the answers, there doesn't seem to be an in-built method in Java for performing arbitrary conversions on numbers, so I put together a simple but usable custom implementation. I created a utility class `MathSequence`:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MathSequence {

    private interface MathOperation {
        double operate(double value);
    }

    private class AddOperation implements MathOperation {

        private double operand;

        public AddOperation(double operand) {
            this.operand = operand;
        }

        public double operate(double value) {
            return value + operand;
        }
    }

    private class SubtractOperation implements MathOperation {

        private double operand;

        public SubtractOperation(double operand) {
            this.operand = operand;
        }

        public double operate(double value) {
            return value - operand;
        }
    }

    private class MultiplyOperation implements MathOperation {

        private double operand;

        public MultiplyOperation(double operand) {
            this.operand = operand;
        }

        public double operate(double value) {
            return value * operand;
        }
    }

    private class DivideOperation implements MathOperation {

        private double operand;

        public DivideOperation(double operand) {
            this.operand = operand;
        }

        public double operate(double value) {
            return value / operand;
        }   
    }

    private List<MathOperation> operations;

    public MathSequence() {
        operations = new LinkedList<MathOperation>();
    }

    public void appendAddOperation(double operand) {
        operations.add(new AddOperation(operand));
    }

    public void appendSubtractOperation(double operand) {
        operations.add(new SubtractOperation(operand));
    }

    public void appendMultiplyOperation(double operand) {
        operations.add(new MultiplyOperation(operand));
    }

    public void appendDivideOperation(double operand) {
        operations.add(new DivideOperation(operand));
    }

    public void clearOperations() {
        operations.clear();
    }

    public double process(double value) {
        for(MathOperation operation : operations) {
            value = operation.operate(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Then I changed my `ObserverTextField` class:

```
public class ObserverTextField extends JTextField implements Observer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private NumberFormat formatter;
    private MathSequence sequence;

    public ObserverTextField() {
        formatter = new DecimalFormat("");
        sequence = new MathSequence();
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(Object value) {
        int integerValue = (int)value;
        setText(formatter.format(sequence.process(integerValue)));
    }

    public NumberFormat getFormat() {
        return formatter;
    }

    public void setFormat(NumberFormat formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    public MathSequence getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(MathSequence sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }
}
```

I can then write code like the following:

```
MathSequence sequence = new MathSequence();
sequence.appendDivideOperation(1000);

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

ObserverTextField actuatorCurrentTextField;
actuatorCurrentTextField = new ObserverTextField();
actuatorCurrentTextField.setSequence(sequence);
actuatorCurrentTextField.setFormat(formatter);
```

This will display the representation as I like it. Because of this approach, I don't hardcode the representation of values within the `ObserverTextField` classes themselves, and so I'm free to vary the representation at run-time and re-use code pretty easily. This is why I couldn't accept suggestions along the lines of "why not just do (int)value/1000?".

I'll accept one of the other answers even though I'll likely stick with this one for the time being, since they're pretty informative.